# Coldfusion Compare Two Query Results from Same Database

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, compare

I've done some research on this site for an issue I'm having, however, I'm finding that the solution is not exactly what I'm looking for, or the implementation doesn't relate to what I'm trying to do. Or, simply put, I just can't seem to figure it out. Here is my issue.

We have a monthly query that we would run that we would send to a third party of physicians, their degree, specialty and clinic. I have the query established already. But recently they wanted to just have us export new results from the previous months data, instead of the whole results list. So, I thought I would create a tool that I would start out simply importing the previous months data. And then taking the query I had been using, putting that in a coldfusion page, run it, and it would show me new records ran for the current month we're in, to the previous month. When I run the report of new data each month, it would save that data in the database with the columns r_month and r_year, which simply means report month/year. So to initially populate the database I just imported Octobers data so I can have a base with the r_month/year being "10" and "2014" respectively. There are 674 records. Then created my page and had a button that would run the same query, save those results, which the r_month and r_year is saved as "11" and "2014" respectively. When I do that, I have 682 records. So, for the month of November, there are 8 "different" or new records from the previous month (October). My question is, what is the best way to run a query that takes the data from October (10/2014) and compare it to the November's data (11/2014), and just give me the new 8 records that were new from November.

Sorry this is long, but wanted to give you guys a detail so you have as much information as possible. I don't really have a code sample I can provide, because apparently the way I was attempting before (using loops etc.) was just not working. Tried looping through previous month query and current month query, trying to find a difference, but that wasn't working. Once again, I've tried using similar samples I've found on here, but they are either not what I'm looking for, or I just can't figure them out. Basically at the end of the process, there needs to be a button that only exports the new records (in this example, the 8) into an excel sheet that we can simply email them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need a separate table? Why not just add some sort of timestamp column that indicates when a record was last updated? Then simply filter on WHERE LastUpdated >= {startOfThisMonth} AND LastUpdated < {startOfNextMonth}? Then way you could easily retrieve new or changed records.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION 1 -** Since you are using SQL server you can do this pretty easily within the query. You have already logged the previous data so you presumably have a key for the "old" physicians in your log table. Try something like this:

```
<cfquery name="getNewPHys" datasource="#dsn#">
SELECT   * 
FROM     sourceTable 
WHERE    physID NOT IN 
         (SELECT physID FROM logtable 
          WHERE  daterange between #somerange# AND #someotherrange#)
</cfquery>
```

You would have to add your own values and vars but you get the idea.

NOTE: This is psuedo-code. you would OF COURSE use cfqueryparam for any of your variables.

**SOLUTION 2**
Another way to do this is by using a dateadded or lastUPdated table. Every time a row is updated you update the *lastupdated* column with the current date/time. Then selecting recent records is a matter of selecting any records which have been updated within your range. Taht's what Leigh suggested in her comment.

I would add one other comment. You seem to be trying to solve this problem without changing anything in your data table. That's not going to work. You need to think about your schema a bit more. For exmaple, solution 2 would involve adding an additional column and you could even add a MSSQL *trigger* that automatically updated that field whenever the record was updated. Wouldn't that work?

I still think we are missing something. Are you perchance *overwriting* your data each time? Or producing *duplicate* records - 674 this month, 682 next month with duplicates?  If so, that's what you need to correct. Anything else is going to be a bolt on solution that creates *more* problems down the road.

Comment: Joshua - sorry about the premeture post - accidentily hit the save button :)

Comment: Shame on you, Mark! `CFQueryParam`!

Comment: Not in queries are simple and intutive.  They also tend to be slow.  Something like "where somefield in (select somefield from whereever where I want it except select somefield from whereever where I don't want it)" usually faster.

Comment: Mark, thank you for your assistance. However, all the data is in 1 table, and is separated by the r_month/r_year columns. There is no type of physid. I was wanting to do a column by column comparison or almost a row by row, and output which one is different from the new query to the old one. Does this make sense? I understand what your example is showing, but I'm assuming the example is using 2 different tables? This is all in one table. The base data (October) is there, as well as the data for november from the query I ran. Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: @cfqueryparam - ha! I'm sorry, I was being expediant.

Comment: Well, you COULD select from your original table in the subselect if that works for you, and make the WHERE clause whatever you like. However, without some real data it's hard to advise you here. MOreover your table should have a primary key of SOME kind (which is what I represented by physid - don't you have a PK defined?). I'll edit my response with 2 additional possibilities.

Comment: @Joshua Mark is right in his comment-response. Your question gave all the details except sample data. Show us a data set (it doesn't have to be every column, though for your sake, the column names you do provide (relevant to a where clause) should be accurate.).

Comment: *There is no type of physid* But it must have some type of PK, otherwise how could you differentiate between two physicians with the same name? Can you post the DDL of your table?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Add a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186241.aspx) to your table.  Make sure you persist the data so you can index it.  The computation should result in values like '201401' for January 2014, etc.  Let's call that column YearMonth

Then your code and query looks like this:

```
ControlYearMonth = "201410";  // October 2014

<cfquery>
select field1, field2, etc
from yourtable
where YearMonth = <cfqueryparam value="#ControlYearMonth#">
except
select field1, field2, etc
from yourtable
where YearMonth < <cfqueryparam value="#ControlYearMonth#">
<cfquery>
```